# system.diagnostics wcf tracing does not show the service end point that raises an exception

Tags: c#, wcf, system.diagnostics

I have added system.diagnostics wcf tracing to my window service that hosts couple of wcf end points.
Because this is a production service i have reduce the 'switchValue' to "Error, Critical, Warning" in order to avoid huge trace files. The problem is that now when I get an exception in the trace there is no reference as to which end point had raised the exception.

Example for such an entry in the trace file bellow.

Thanks

> 

```
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>131075</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-07-04T12:21:06.1749193Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="Adapter" ProcessID="3440" ThreadID="107" />
    <Channel />
    <Computer>XX-01</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
        <DataItem>
            <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
                <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
                <Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
                <AppDomain>Casino3rdPartyAdapter.exe</AppDomain>
                <Exception>
                    <ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
                    <Message>The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.</Message>
                    <StackTrace>
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowHttpProtocolException(String message, HttpStatusCode statusCode, String statusDescription)
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.GetMessageBuffer()
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.DecodeBufferedMessageAsync()
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.BeginParse()
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.BeginParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginParseIncomingMessage(AsyncCallback asynCallback, Object state)
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.EnqueueContext(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult)
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContextCore(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult)
                        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContext(IAsyncResult result)
                        at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
                        at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
                        at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
                        at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.IOCompleted(ListenerAsyncResult asyncResult, UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes)
                        at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
                        at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
                    </StackTrace>
                    <ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.</ExceptionString>
                    <DataItems>
                        <Data>
                            <Key>System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.HttpStatusCode</Key>
                            <Value>RequestEntityTooLarge</Value>
                        </Data>
                    </DataItems>
                </Exception>
            </TraceRecord>
        </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
```

Comment: As far as I know, diagnostics is configured on the entire service. When an exception occurs, diagnostics does not know which endpoint has the exception. I think you can open the log on the client side and record it when an exception occurs when accessing a certain endpoint.

Comment: unfortunately, i do not have access to the client. If set the switch value fo the trace to 'Information, ActivityTracing' the trace will show me which end point threw the exception.

Comment: If you set the traced switch value to switchValue, will the trace not show you which endpoint caused the exception?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, SwitchValu can only be of predefined values as mentioned above.

Comment: If you are using a user-defined trace source, set the switchValue property to "Warning, ActivityTracing".For more information about it,please refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/recommended-settings-for-tracing-and-message-logging